# Android Virtual Device Manager Requirments?

Tags: android, performance, hardware

Can any one say what is the basic requirements (i.e) HardWare Specificaion needed to run the AVD Manager in Eclipse
I already Installed Eclipse and AVD Manager but it responding very slow
I did not install any other software apart from JDK,eclipse and ADT Bundle Its a Fresh System.
Only one thing I do when runs the AVD that  Chrome and Mozila in open state 
My System Specification is 
Processor: i3 (3.30Ghz)
RAM :4Gb
My Question Is 
Using above configuration but AVD is responding slow . What I want to do to make AVD fatser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is fine, there are two ways that made my emulator faster:

1. While creating a virtual device using AVD, Use X86 instead of ARM. Now download the HAXM tool from the SDK manager in the extras section and install it. Now your new emulator based on intel will me as fast as a phone.(Only for intel based chips supporting Virtualization.)
   [image]
   [For more on this option.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856866/2219600)
2. If option one does not work for you. Just start using [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator(Free for personal use). Its awesome.

Comment: How to Download HAXM tool

Comment: Just go to your sdk manager from eclipse or studio, you will find it in the extras section. Check the edited answer, upvote if it helped you.

Comment: how to use genymotion emulator

Comment: Its very simple. Register in their site and download their emulator. After installing add the your android sdk path to it. Now every time you run your android app. The genymotion emulator will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try Manymo online emulator [For More Details click here](https://www.manymo.com/%E2%80%8E)